# how to add id and extra parameters to a Magnific popup iframe with youtube video, so I can control with with API youtube player

Tags: javascript, api, iframe, youtube, magnific-popup

how to add an iframe id and an extra parameters (wmode=opaque&enablejsapi=1&origin=https://www.example.com) to a Magnific popup iframe with a youtube video, so I can control it with API youtube player?

Answer (score 2):

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#iframe_type

```
iframe: {
  patterns: {
    youtube: {
      src: '//www.youtube.com/embed/%id%?autoplay=1'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, sorry for answering before, reading source code I found out the solution. Again thanks